# How to divide all rows in a panda Dataframe except for one specific row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I am working with a `pandas.DataFrame` that I need to divide the entire dataframe by a certain value except for one row.  It is easy to divide the entire dataframe by one value, however I would like to keep one of the rows the exact same.  For example, if I had a dataframe like below:

```
  A      B      C      D
10000  10000  10000  10000 
10000  10000  10000  10000 
10000  10000  10000  10000 
10000  10000  10000  10000 
  1      1      1      1   
10000  10000  10000  10000 
10000  10000  10000  10000
```

I want to divide all of the rows by the value of 1000 except for the 5th row, which I would like all the values to stay the same of 1.  So, the new dataframe would look like this:

```
 A   B   C   D
10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10
 1   1   1   1   
10  10  10  10 
10  10  10  10
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?  I feel like I am missing something very basic.  I have tried using loc, iloc, mul, & div but can not get them to work concurrently.

Comment: Do you have to select that one row by value or by index?

Comment: I have to select it by index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you save the row of interest, and then divide the entire dataframe by the desired value.  You can then restore the row of interest afterwards.

#### Code:

```
def df_divide_by_excect_row(in_df, divisor, row_to_ignore):
    row_to_save = in_df.iloc[row_to_ignore]
    new_df = in_df / divisor
    new_df.iloc[row_to_ignore] = row_to_save
    return new_df
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
      A      B      C      D
    10000  10000  10000  10000 
    10000  10000  10000  10000 
    10000  10000  10000  10000 
    10000  10000  10000  10000 
      1      1      1      1   
    10000  10000  10000  10000 
    10000  10000  10000  10000"""), header=1)

print(df)
print(df_divide_by_excect_row(df, 1000, 4))
```

#### Results:

```
       A      B      C      D
0  10000  10000  10000  10000
1  10000  10000  10000  10000
2  10000  10000  10000  10000
3  10000  10000  10000  10000
4      1      1      1      1
5  10000  10000  10000  10000
6  10000  10000  10000  10000

      A     B     C     D
0  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
1  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
2  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
3  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
4   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
5  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
6  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional list comprehension to select all rows bar the one ignored.

```
n = 1000 
ignored_row = 4
df.iloc[[i for i in range(len(df)) if i != ignored_row], :] /= n
>>> df
    A   B   C   D
0  10  10  10  10
1  10  10  10  10
2  10  10  10  10
3  10  10  10  10
4   1   1   1   1
5  10  10  10  10
6  10  10  10  10
```

As pointed out by @DSM, you could use the vectorized version for much better performance on dataframes with many rows:

```
df.loc[np.arange(len(df)) != 4] /= n
```

Comment: There's a vectorized equivalent too, `df.loc[np.arange(len(df)) != 4] /= n`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help!